# Redirecting to index page

Tags: php, redirect

I tried redirecting my play.php(main page) to my index page, where the user needs to log in. It works. However, users can't log into the play.php, because it keeps redirecting. I used the codes below to achieve that. I placed it immediately after the body tag()

```
<?php 
  header("Location: index.php"); 
  exit();

?>
```

Comment: You have to check if someone's already logged in, and only redirect if he's not..?!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any code that checks if there's a logged in user.  You should wrap the header() call in an if that checks if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no condition for getting user logged in or not. You should create a function that checks user status and returns true or false. Create a check function with name isUserLoggedIn and use it this way:

```
<?php 
if(!isUserLoggedIn()){
  header("Location: http://example.com/index.php"); 
  exit();
}    
?>
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `Location` header should *always* include a fully-qualified path, which would consist of not only the document location but host information as well.